# CSS transition with AngularJS animate service doesn't work properly

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
 $scope.myImgClass = 'start-class';
});
app.animation('.fadeOut', function(){
 return {
  enter: function(element, parentElement, afterElement, doneCallback){},
  leave: function(element, doneCallback){},
  move: function(element, parentElement, afterElement, doneCallback){},
  addClass: function(element, className, done){
   jQuery(element).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 3000);
  },
  removeClass: function(element, className, done){
   jQuery(element).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000);
  }
 };
});
```

```css
.shrink-add, .shrink-remove{
  -webkit-transition:all ease 2.5s;
  -moz-transition:all ease 2.5s;
  -o-transition:all ease 2.5s;
  transition:all ease 2.5s;
}
.shrink,
.shrink-add.shrink-add-active{
  height: 100px;
}

.start-class,
.shrink-remove.shrink-remove-active{
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title>AngularJS $animate Service</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/animate.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
  <h3>Image Animation</h3>
  <input type="button" ng-click="myImgClass='shrink'" value="Small"/>
  <input type="button" ng-click="myImgClass=''" value="Big"/>
  <hr>
  <img ng-class="myImgClass" src="http://vriz.net/vriz/nma/ch25/static/images/arch.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Question]**

CSS Transition for increasing size of image works, but doesn't work for decreasing.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Does anyone know how to fix it?
Does anyone know how to fix it?
Does anyone know how to fix it?
Does anyone know how to fix it?
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your transition does not work when going from big to small is because when the image is big all of the classes are removed which is basically setting the `img` to `height: auto`.

In order to get the shrink to work you need to set a height value for the image when it is in the "big" state. You can do this by adding a class to the image like so:

`<img ng-class="myImgClass" src="http://vriz.net/vriz/nma/ch25/static/images/arch.jpg" class="big-image" />`

Then setting the css like so:

```
.big-image {
    height: 400px;
}
```

This will make it so the image in the "big" state will have a set height attribute and when the small button is clicked the class that gets applied will overwrite that height attribute with the "small" state css.

**CSS transitions will only work if they have explicitly set attributes that the transition can go between.**

Hopefully this makes sense.